# Open Graph protocol: What to do when an image doesn't exist on the page?

Tags: open-graph-protocol

The [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/#metadata) states that every page is required to have 4 properties:

- title
- type
- url
- image

For example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

In my case, many of my website's pages do not have an image on the page. What should I do in this scenario considering the protocol *requires* the image property?

Answer (score 1):

The image property references an image that represents the object (a page in this instance). It doesn't need to refer to an image that is actually on the page. In fact, it is quite probable that any one image on a web page might not faithfully represent that page.

So, just use another image. (?) Preferably one that does represent the pages content.